# PHPMailer being rejected with "Host impersonating" when script run from CLI (cron)

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer

I host a site through bluehost.com, which has an email function that I've built around PHPMailer. It has been running fine, but it looks like bluehost have changed some security settings in the last 24 hours. Having debugged through it, I'm at a loss how to resolve this.

It looks like bluehost have configured their end to now validate the host that is connecting to the SMTP server. If I trigger an email while browsing the site, the email still sends fine:

```
SERVER -> CLIENT: 220-box304.bluehost.com ESMTP Exim 4.86_2 #1 Wed, 20 Jul 2016 10:16:19 -0600 220-We do not authorize the use of this system to transport unsolicited, 220 and/or bulk e-mail.
CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO www.fydentry.com
SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-box304.bluehost.com Hello www.fydentry.com [69.89.31.104]250-SIZE 52428800250-8BITMIME250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN250 HELP
CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH LOGIN
...
SERVER -> CLIENT: 235 Authentication succeeded
```

Some (most) emails aren't sent interactively though, and are queued in a database, which a php script periodically executes in the background via a cron job, to send those emails out. This used to work fine, but as of yesterday, the script now throws errors:

```
SERVER -> CLIENT: 220-box304.bluehost.com ESMTP Exim 4.86_2 #1 Wed, 20 Jul 2016 10:30:08 -0600 220-We do not authorize the use of this system to transport unsolicited, 220 and/or bulk e-mail.
CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO box304.bluehost.com
SERVER -> CLIENT: 550 "REJECTED - Bad HELO - Host impersonating [box304.bluehost.com]"
SMTP ERROR: EHLO command failed: 550 "REJECTED - Bad HELO - Host impersonating [box304.bluehost.com]"
CLIENT -> SERVER: HELO box304.bluehost.com
SERVER -> CLIENT: 550 "REJECTED - Bad HELO - Host impersonating [box304.bluehost.com]"
SMTP ERROR: HELO command failed: 550 "REJECTED - Bad HELO - Host impersonating [box304.bluehost.com]"
CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 box304.bluehost.com closing connection
SMTP connect() failed.
```

I can see that the interactive log identifies the source site www.fydentry.com, but the php script executed via the cli (cron), just sees the box name, and decides that isn't a valid source.

Is there a parameter I can add to the command line, so that the script appears to be running from the site address? Or something I can do within the PHP script to emulate this? Or is this a config issue on the bluehost side, that I should be asking them to rectify? Or have I totally missed something here, and there's something else I should have done?

At the moment I've hacked around the issue by calling a basic wrapper script in the cron job, which in turn executes this:

```
file_get_contents("http://www.fydentry.com/my-mailer-script.php");
```

Which seems to sufficiently fool everything that the script is running from the site. But that doesn't seem like a good long term solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem occur yesterday. I could only imagine all of the problems people are having with this now.

Anyways, since you have built this around the PHPMailer class try and set the "Helo" property on your mail object. This worked for me.

From the documentation(http://phpmailer.worxware.com/?pg=properties):

> $Helo  public      Sets the SMTP HELO of the message (Default is $Hostname)

Hope this helps!

Comment: That's the one, thanks! I've changed the code to set the Hostname property (which in turn sets Helo as well), and everything is back to working. As for Bluehost randomly changing stuff like this with no notification, and no ability to get help or info from anyone ("we don't support third party apps - no information on what we've changed for you"), yeah, well...

Comment: Great, glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

This resolved it for me:

```
$mail->Hostname = "yourhostname.com";
$mail->Helo = $mail->Hostname;
```